# What will be the playing position of Thomas Muller? Will he play as CF?

Tags: football, world-cup, formations

Thomas Müller of Germany was a midfielder in the last World Cup in 2014.
In this World Cup some news on the Internet claim that Müller will play as a forward. So, what will be his position during the tournament?

Comment: As the first match has [shown](https://youtu.be/6wGCEAw5Ptw?t=30s), Thomas Müller is playing as a right winger.

Answer (score 2):

He mainly plays center forward or right winger, although he is often listed as striker. ([source](https://www.transfermarkt.com/thomas-muller/profil/spieler/58358))

His last games for Germany he played midfielder as well with Timo Werner or Mario Gomez being the only striker (for example [here](https://www.transfermarkt.com/spielbericht/index/spielbericht/3023575) and [here](https://www.transfermarkt.com/spielbericht/index/spielbericht/2959076)).

It's pretty safe to assume that he'll play on that position in the World Cup as well, but who knows what Joachim Löw got up his sleeve.